# Faces of convex cones

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

Let $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed, convex, pointed cone and $\text{dim}K=n$. A convex cone $F\subset K$ is called a face if $F=K\cap H$, where $H$ is a supporting hyperplane of $K$. Assume that $(F_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of faces of $K$ such that $F_k \not\subset F_{k'}$ for every $k\neq k' $. My question is whether we can deduce that $\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty F_k=\{0\}$? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think so. Let $L$ be a closed, convex, pointed cone with (at least) countably many, disjoint (up to $0$) faces $\{F_k\}$, e.g., the Lorentz cone. Then, the cone $\mathbb R^+ \times L$ has the faces $\{\mathbb R^+ \times F_k\}$ and their intersection is at least $\mathbb R^+ \times \{0\}$.